# Не работает менеджер приложений в ubuntu 20

Tags: linux, ubuntu

После обновления Ubuntu 18.04 до версии 20.04 пропал менеджер приложений. Понятно что есть терминал для установки/удаления софта но перфекционизм берет верх.. Как починить? Куда лезть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мой перфекционизм приходит к противоположным выводам: если уже есть терминал для установки/удаления софта, то зачем еще какая-то муть...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .....

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: Спасибо, это мне помогло!!